# Origin of 'dap' shoe

Tags: etymology, british-english, dialects

What is origin of '***dap'*** as name for canvas shoes which is used  in parts of England such as [West Country & Wales](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimsoll_shoe)?

*The Chamber Dictionary* has the following entry but no suggestion for its origin:

***[Dap:](https://books.google.it/books?id=pz2ORay2HWoC&pg=PP11&lpg=PP11&dq=dap%20shoe%20etymology&source=bl&ots=FH7_qfd414&sig=eaIetQp7rm2N0e2yt5dER_AlBj4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgv9OB1-ffAhUC_qQKHbeJBHEQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=dap%20shoe%20etymology&f=false)***

> Dap (dialect) n. a gym shoe, plimsoll.

Does anyone have more information on its possible origin?

Comment: this subject has its own wikipedia page

Answer (score 6):

#### To Dap

In various English dialects the verb [*to dap*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924088038397/page/n35) means ‘to move quickly and lightly; to trip along’:

> North Yorkshire: He goes *dapping* along, as if he were on springs.
>   Somerset: I was always quick *to dap* about on my feet.
>   Devon: Her were terribly spry. Her *dapped* round like anything. — Joseph Wright, ed., *English Dialect Dictionary*, vol. 2, D–G, 1900.

The number of times a stone skips across water does so in a series of *daps*, and *The Welshman*, 9 Feb. 1855, describes waterfowl as “[*dippers, dappers, divers*](https://newspapers.library.wales/view/4348357/4348364/58/dappers)”: a dipper like a duck or swan, a diver like a cormorant, and a dapper like a kingfisher that skims the surface of the water.

According to Wright, the verb was common across Ireland, Yorkshire, Wiltshire, Gloucester-shire, Wales, the West Country, and the Isle of Wight.

Transferred to a vertical plane, it means ’to bounce’, as in the description of the first football play in Cardiff (1873–4):

> There were twenty players a-side, the ball was round, not oval, and was never to be picked up off the ground, but had to be [*dapping*](https://newspapers.library.wales/view/4227400/4227404/99/dapping), if only a few inches.  — *Evening Express*, Final Football Edition (Cardiff), 7 Dec. 1907.

I’m trying to envision football with basketball rules but it just wouldn’t be the same.

*Dapping* is also a special fishing technique where the bait or fly on a very short line is bobbed rapidly in the water. This usage has also reached America:

> One of the major advantages of [*dapping*](https://books.google.de/books?id=qKZtHyO7IvAC&pg=PA116&dq=dapping&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA75SzuOjfAhUup4sKHRdiDVMQ6AEIMjAC) is that you avoid entering the stream at all. Too often, wading into a creek either disturbs the trout or puts them down completely.  — *Field & Stream* 91/12 (Apr. 1987), 116.

It makes sense, then, that a shoe designed for “moving quickly and lightly” would eventually recruit this word in at least some of the dialects where it was found.

#### Daps

Although some sources, such as the [*Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang*](https://books.google.de/books?id=h0mcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&dq=Slang+daps&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid8dTmk-ffAhXHposKHQlZA88Q6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=Slang%20daps&f=false) (2nd ed., 2015), date the print debut of *daps*, ‘ rubber-soled canvas shoes’, to 1924, daps were tripping lightly across Cardiff somewhat earlier, at least when there was no mud:

> This must have been a great disappointment to the men wearing [“rubber daps,”](https://newspapers.library.wales/view/4214670/4214674/116/daps) as with these it was impossible to get a foothold, and it was anticipated that fast time under these conditions would be out of the question. — *Evening Express*, Football Edition (Cardiff), 12 Feb. 1910.

The quotation marks suggest a fairly new and/or slang word, so calling these shoes *daps* in print likely means that in 1910, people in Cardiff hadn’t been doing so for all that long in everyday speech. The shoes occasionally make appearances in Cardiff and Bristol newspapers thereafter:

> …and Manley, who, taking with him four pairs of leather soled [*daps*](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000264/19220908/001/0003), eight pairs socks, and a pair of leather shoes, arrived in Berkeley last evening, … — *Western Daily Press* (Bristol), 8 Sept. 1922. BNA (paywall)
>
> …but we are urgently in need of [*daps*](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000264/19230308/038/0006), shorts, and light sweaters, so that the boys may get the full advantage of the training … — *Western Daily Press* (Bristol), 8 Mar. 1923.  BNA (paywall)
>
> She even said there was no need for little Betty to take her [*daps*](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000104/19230830/308/0013) out on the pavement and shake the sand out of them. — *Western Mail* (Cardiff), 30 Aug. 1923. BNA (paywall)

#### Dappers

My search of relevant newspapers yielded no earlier usage of *dappers* with the same meaning as *daps*, though an ordinary web search has ample results today. This suggests that *daps* is not an abbreviated form of *dappers*, but that the longer word is a more modern extension.

This does not hold, however, for the original verb, which may very well be a derivative of *dapper*.

[*Dapper*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dapper#etymonline_v_769) entered English from Middle Dutch/Low German *dapper*, ‘bold, strong, sturdy’ (Cf. ModGer *tapfer*, ‘brave, courageous’) in the mid-15th c. with the familiar meaning of ‘elegant, neat trim’, but somewhat later expanded to include ‘quick, nimble’ and by the 17th c. ‘small and active, nimble, brisk, lively’. You get to brisk and lively from heavy, strong, and sturdy the same way Robin Hood called his companion “Little John.”

> …with her a little lad naked and blind, yet did i note, that bow and shafts he had, and two wings to his shoulders fixt, which stood like little Sayles, with farre more various colours mixt, then be your peacocks Tayles; i seeing this little dapper Elfe, such Armes as these to beare, quoth i thus softly to my selfe, what strange thing haue we here, i neuer saw the like thought i: t’is more then strange to me, to haue a child haue wings to fly, and yet want eyes to see; … Michael Drayton, *The Muses Elizium*, 1630. EEBO

Since this “dapper elf” blind Cupid is naked, it’s not likely Drayton has a snappy dresser in mind, but certainly something nimble and quick.

A derivation of *dap* from *dapper* in the quick and nimble sense does equal service, however, for those who’d prefer to be snappy dressers, which may have contributed to extending *daps* to *dappers* after the verb became obsolete.

One folk etymology that doesn’t work, however,  is deriving *daps* as an acronym from the factory name “[Dunlop Athletic Plimsoles,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimsoll_shoe)” as Dunlop did not take over the original manufacturer, the Liverpool Rubber Company, until 1925, fifteen years after the first mention in Cardiff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe DAP for canvas shoes comes from the acronym:
Dunlop Athletic Plimsolls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The "plimsoll" Wikipedia page refutes this ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimsoll_(shoe)